# can react-native-root-siblings work with react-redux

Tags: react-native

in a handleClick function, update the rootSiblings like this,

```
handleClick() { this.progressBar.update( <ProgressBar /> ); }
```

and in ProgressBar component,

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { View } from 'react-native';
const getFinishedWidth = progress => ({ width: progress * totalWidth });
const getUnfinishedWidth = progress => ({ width: (1 - progress) * totalWidth }); 
function CustomerReassignProgressBar(props) { 
const { progress } = props; 
return ( 
<View style={styles.bar}> 
<View style={getFinishedWidth(progress)} /> 
<View style={getUnfinishedWidth(progress)} /> 
</View> ); 
} 
CustomerReassignProgressBar.propTypes = { progress: PropTypes.number, };
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ progress: state.batchReassignProgress, }); 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProgressBar);
```

then, when calling handleClick(), the app crushed, the error is, 'Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(ProgressBar)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(ProgressBar)".'

if I don't use connect in component, it works well. So, I guess, maybe rootSiblings can not work with react-redux. But does anyone knows this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `react-native-root-siblings@4.x`

Then

```
import { setSiblingWrapper } from 'react-native-root-siblings';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = xxx;// get your redux store here

// call this before using any root-siblings related code
setSiblingWrapper(sibling => (
   <Provider store={store}>{sibling}</Provider>
));
```